# How to get old terminal output for a currently running program that exceeding the buffer limit?

Tags: python, terminal, console, output, buffer

I am running a python program that is taking a while to run through all the iterations and I have been printing data to the terminal. However, the printed data exceeded the 1000 line limit in VSCode and I cannot go back to the old data which I need. The program has been running for a few hours and has a few hours left and I do not have the time to restart. What can I do to get the old terminal output?

I tried using Chat-GPT to give terminal commands to see the old terminal data but nothing it gave me worked. I can get the process ID and program name.

Comment: unless you were actively capturing the stdout(probably not) or running it via a service that automagically captures stdout(systemctl etc... probably not) ... thats gone ... you cannot get it ... its bytes in the wind

Answer (score 0):

Unless there was a process specifically agg'ing or saving that buffer...it's gone. :-(